# How can i know application installed date in jailbreak iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, date, mobile, jailbreak, iso

I am developing an iPhone 6.0 jailbreak application,  where i need to get an application install date programmatically.

Actually, my application must show installed date **and** update date to my user for specific application. I spend a whole day on this RnD but still not having any success.

please help me to solve this problem. thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: `struct stat st; stat([[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath].UTF8String, &st);` then use the `st_mtime` member of the `st` struct.

Comment: thank you H2CO3 for reply. I am now testing this code with my application.

Comment: Hello H2CO3 how can I know last Update date of application pro-grammatically.

Comment: Examine the documentation of `stat()`.

Comment: @MohitRaval, if you found a solution that works for you, please consider posting the code as an **answer** below.  You can accept your own answer.  Thanks!